# Typescript module usage without ".js" ending

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

In typical JavaScript files we use require('some-module.js') to import functionality of this module where we need.

If we use TypeScript we also want to import this functionality using "import module from 'some-module.js'".

If we use nest.js we import using "import module from 'some-module'". The main thing that there is no ".js". How can i reach the same in for example express application. Maybe i should use webpack, babel or some special tsconfig.json configuration?

Comment: Perhaps you could share some sample code of your specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

With Typescript's `import` and with Node's `require`, the extension is not necessary. Just the path to the file, or the name of the package you're importing. So in typescript you would do `import * as module from 'some-module'` and in js you would do `const module = require('some-module')`. You may want to check out [this page on module resolution in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I checked it out. It is right. I just had an application that I needed to migrate from js to ts. and this problem happened to me. if I “import someModule from './some-module'” it gave me an error like “no such module”. but when i did with .js it worked.
maybe you know why this might happen?